# python web crawler with ticket authentication

Tags: python, cookies, web-crawler

The website I'm trying to crawl have an login page like:

```
<form method="post" action="/login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table><tbody><tr><td>Name</td> 
                  <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>                  
              </tr> 
              <tr><td>Password</td> 
                  <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
              </tr>
       </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="hidden" name="request_uri" value="/index.html">
 <input type="submit" name="Log In" value="Log In">
<p></p></form>
```

An access ticket will be generated by the server after the login data (account and password) have been successfully validated, containing information that will grant access to restricted areas of the site.

This ticket, along with additional data, will be wrapped into a cookie and sent to the browser. This cookie does not contain any life-time or expiration information, and will thus be discarded when the session ends.

How can I login like an user by python?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `requests` module and a POST to login in, then save the cookie. I would recommend using `Fiddler2` to capture the traffic to the website and then build your response such that the payload in your Python code matches the payload expected by the server. Your code would look something like this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://mywebsite.com'
payload = {'user': 'my_usersname', 'password': 'my_password'}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
print r.text  # for Python 3.x use print(r.text)
print r.cookies
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the code. I also tried cookielib, session. But when I grap another page of the website, I still find myself not login, cause the website will check my status. If you're not login , You will be redirect to the login page

Comment: @milowang How does it check your status? Have you used `FIddler2` to see the data sent to the server? You should be able to use `requests` to exactly mimic what the server sees when the data comes from a browser.